# Histogram datetime objects in Numpy

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, histogram

I have an array of datetime objects and I'd like to histogram them in Python.

The Numpy [histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) method doesn't accept datetimes, the error thrown is

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 176, in histogram
mn, mx = [mi+0.0 for mi in range]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

Is there a way to perform this other than manually converting the datetime object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy.histogram` works only with numbers. When `dt_array` is your array of `datetime` objects, this would give you the histogram:

```
to_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.timestamp())
time_stamps = to_timestamp(dt_array)
np.histogram(time_stamps)
```

Answer (score 8):

The `.timestamp()` method only seems to work as of [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).  If you are using an older version of Python, you will need to compute it directly:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

to_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: (x - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
from_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x))

## Compute the histogram
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(to_timestamp(dates))

## Print the histogram, and convert bin edges back to datetime objects
print hist, from_timestamp(bin_edges)
```

Comment: you can also do: `np.vectorize(lambda x: int(x.strftime('%s'))`

Comment: Why do you need to start in 1970? (i.e. `to_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: (x - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())`)

Comment: It seems like:
`to_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: (x - datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1)).total_seconds())

from_timestamp = np.vectorize(lambda x: (datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)) )`

would be more generalized (handles dates since year 1)